# how can I call same __init__.robot file contains(Suite &Test Setup) if i call individual TC or call suite of multiple TCS in a folder in RF

Tags: robotframework

below is my folder structure of test cases,

[image]

I want to call my `__init__.robot` file(which contains Suite Setup and test setup) only once either I run an individual test case or I call the test suite module wise or I call my all the TCS at once, Please help how can I do that in robot framework.

Currently, if I am keeping Suite Setup and test setup in each robot file, I am able to call individually successfully but when I am calling all the test cases under the test case folder at once or module wise, Suite Setup is initializing before each test as it is defined in each .robot file if I am keeping `__init_.robot` (which contains Suite Setup and test setup) at module level then suite setup is initializing only once which is fine but I am unable to run test cases individually as its not calling `__init__.robot`

Answer (score 0):

Put your `__init__.robot` file into the testcase folder, then use the [`--test`](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#by-test-suite-and-test-case-names) argument to call individual tests. In this case the last argument should not be a .robot file, but the `testcase` folder itself.

From the parent directory of `testcases` folder:

```
robot --test 'My test name' testcases
```

Similarly you can use `--suite` and other arguments to select test cases. All of these are described in the User Guide, [Selecting test cases](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#selecting-test-cases) chapter.

Comment: @HEMANTSINHA Glad to hear. In that case please mark the answer as accepted by using the tick mark next to it. So it can be closed. :)